# Зачем при возвращении ссылки объекта класса нужно разыменовывать this ? C++

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, ссылки

Зачем при возвращении ссылки объекта класса нужно разыменовывать this ?
Пример:

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point& operator= (const Point &other)
    {
        this->x = other.x;
        this->y = other.y;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Возвращаемый тип у метода = Point&,
а возвращаем мы *this

Ведь ссылка хранит в себе адрес, как и указатель, но зачем тогда мы разыменовываем указатель this ?

Comment: Ссылка - это ссылка, а не указатель.

Comment: потому что вы возвращаете ссыльку на данный обьект, а не указатель на него...

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните вопрос, вам не понятно почему нельзя указатель сразу ссылке присвоить или почему он к ней автоматом не приводится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в языке С++ ссылка не "хранит в себе адрес". Как внутренне устроена ссылка языком не оговаривается. Ссылочные типы в С++ не являются объектными типами - они формально не обязаны занимать память и, соответственно, "хранить" ничего не обязаны. Как сказано в TC++PL у Страуструпа, один из допустимых неформальных способов представлять ссылки - это думать о них, как об альтернативных *именах* для существующих объектов (или функций).

Во-вторых, тип выражения `this` в вашем случае - `Point *`, а возвращаемый тип вашей функции - `Point &`. Это совершенно разные типы. Язык С++ не будет додумывать за вас. что именно вы хотели сказать, пытаясь возвратить `Point *` там, где требуется `Point &`. Соблюсти соответствие типов в данном случае - ваша задача.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Point a, b, c;
    a = b;
```

тут вы осуществляете присвоение `b`,  и `a` становится таким как `b` (чтоб вам было понять попроще), и  именно этот обьект вам нужен после присвоения (`*this` для `a` это и есть `a`),  вторая причина целесообразности возвращения ссыльки, а не копии, заключается в возможности написать следующее:

```
b = c = a;
```

`(b = c)` это ссылька на `b`, которому присваивается `a`; `(c = a)` это ссылька на `c` и т. д.
Еще добавлю, что ссылька не может в себе хранить ничего, так как ссылька всего лишь имя, она не занимает область памяти, чтоб еще чего то хранить...

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле ссылка и указатель функционально действительно одно и то же. Даже Ваше "хранит в себе" тут не подходит. По факту в любой реализации ссылка и указатель ничем не отличаются. И я не понимаю людей, которые предлагаю искуственно думать о ссылке, как об каком-то сферическом коне в вакууме.

Но синтаксически, с точки зрения языка, это вещи разные. Собственно ссылка и была введена в язык Си++ потому, что в ряде случаев с ней удобнее, чем с указателем. Можно сказать, что это просто разный взгляд на одну и ту же вещь.

Никогда не забывайте, что компьютер не умеет думать, он всегда делает только то, что ему сказано, причем с точностью до каждой буквы.

В данном случае разработчикам языка было просто лениво делать исключение для одного единственного случая, когда в принципе разных толкований особо и нет. Значительно проще заставить всех указать разыменование. Так что просто смиритесь и запомните, без вопроса зачем.

Comment: Бррррррррррр...